# Autoit click on current cursor position

Tags: click, cursor, autoit

I have a swing ui with text box and button. I want to enter values in text box and click button using Autoit.
What I did was

```
Send("textvalue")
Send("{TAB}")//This will move to the button
```

I tried Controlclick method after it. But it not working.
Is there any method in which get the current cursor position I mean tab position and fire click directly. please help me

Answer (score 0):

To Press a Button you can do a "Click" on it. but you already focused it with TAB, so the easier way would be to Send a Enter. Try this:

> Send("textvalue") Send("{TAB}") Send("{Enter}")

or (thanks to the comment)

> Send("textvalue") Send("{TAB}") Send("{Space}")

Comment: Enter not working. I need a solution in away with Controlclick

Comment: then try
ControlClick("[ACTIVE]", "", ControlGetFocus("[ACTIVE]"))

Comment: Tried but not working. Button created using Swing java.

Comment: On tab it is going to the button because the button text got highlighted. But Controlclick not working.

Comment: Have you tried to `Send( '{SPACE}' )` instead of `Send( '{ENTER}' )`? Sometimes this works better.